# Unable to communicate between pods running on different nodes in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, locust

I have been building a distributed load testing application using Kubernetes and Locust ([similar to this](https://medium.com/locust-io-experiments/locust-io-experiments-running-in-kubernetes-95447571a550)).

I currently have a multi-node cluster running on bare-metal (running on an Ubuntu 18.04 server, set up using Kubeadm, and with Flannel as my pod networking addon).

The architecture of my cluster is as follows:

- I have a 'master instance' of the Locust application running on my master node.
- I have 'slave instances' of the Locust application running on all of my other nodes. These slave instances must be able to bind to a port (5558 by default) of the master instance.

As of now, I don't believe that that is [happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StoRt.png). My cluster shows that all of my deployments are [healthy and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mok1L.png), however I am unable to access the logs of any of my slave instances which are running on nodes other than my master node. This leads me to believe that my pods are unable to communicate with each other across different nodes.

Is this an issue with my current [networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) or [deployment](https://github.com/karol-brejna-i/locust-experiments/tree/master/kubernetes) setups (I followed the linked guides pretty-much verbatim)? Where should I start in debugging this issue?

Comment: Can pods connect to another pod within same host?

Comment: So that `10.0.2.15:10250` i/o timeout is almost certainly the firewall failing to expose the kubelet port to the outside world; `kubectl logs` contacts the API server to obtain the correct URL, but then redirects `kubectl` _directly to the Node_ to obtain the logs (otherwise the logs would have to travel from the Node through the API server down to you, which would be a huge bottleneck) -- you _should_ fix the firewall, but in the interim you can ssh onto the Nodes and use `docker logs` to have a peek for yourself what's going on

Comment: @BMW pods within the same host are able to connect to each other

Answer (score 0):

How slaves instances try to join the master instance. You have to create master service (with labels) to access master pod. Also, make sure your SDN is up and master is reachable to slave instances. You can test using telnet to master pod IP from slave instances.

Comment: Slave instances of my application join the master instance through binding to a port exposed on the master container (5557-5558 I believe). As far as my SDN, Flannel is up and running on all of my nodes, but the core of my problem is that the slave instances cannot connect to my master instance. They can connect to my master instance when I have my master instance and slave instances running in the same node, but I'm getting that timeout/connection error when I have a slave instance trying to connect to the master from another node

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the problem I can guess that you have a connection problem caused by firewall or network misconfiguration.

From the network perspective, there are requirements mentioned in Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/):

> - all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
> - all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without NAT
> - the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others see it as

From the firewall perspective, you need to ensure the cluster traffic can pass the firewall on the nodes.

Here is the list of ports you should have opened on the nodes [provided](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes-networking.md) by CoreOS website:

```
Master node inbound: TCP: 443  from Worker Nodes, API Requests, and End-Users
                     UDP: 8285,8472 from Master & Worker Nodes


Worker node inbound: TCP: 10250 from Master Nodes
                     TCP: 10255 from Heapster
                     TCP: 30000-32767 from External Application Consumers
                     TCP: 1-32767 from Master & Worker Nodes
                     TCP: 179 from Worker Nodes
                     UDP: 8472 from Master & Worker Nodes
                     UPD: 179 from Worker Nodes

Etcd node inbound:  TCP: 2379-2380 from Master & Worker Nodes
```

Comment: Please excuse my lack of understanding in this as I'm completely new to K8s, but I'd need to manually open those ports on my nodes? Just to give some more context, I'm joining nodes to my cluster via the "kubeadm join" command; that command doesn't take care of exposing those ports for me? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your firewall policy. If you have default rule Deny/Drop, you should explicitly allow all that traffic. If you have default rule Allow/Pass, just check that some deny rules wouldn't block that traffic before it reaches "default allow". In the very beginning of Kubernetes learning I would suggest you to build your cluster inside the trusted network and do not use firewall on the nodes or add your cluster network interfaces to the trusted zone in firewall settings on all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Right now I'm running the cluster on VMs/Bare-Metal. My master node is running on an Ubuntu machine, and that same machine is running VirtualBox, and spinning up my VM worker nodes. I don't believe that this is a firewall issue then? Because all of my nodes are communicating on a host-only network in promiscuous mode?

Answer (score 0):

see ip forwarding is enabled on all the nodes.

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

if not enable it like this and test it.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```